# Mismatched input ',' expecting ')' - Trying to convert to version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

I'm trying to get this code run in version 5 but can't figure out what is wrong.

Error Message:

```
line 15: Mismatched input ',' expecting ')'
```

The Line:

```
xATRTrailingStop := if(src_ > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src_[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), math.max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src_ - nLoss), if(src_ < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src_[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), math.min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src_ + nLoss), if(src_ > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src_ - nLoss, src_ + nLoss)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_switch

```
xATRTrailingStop := switch
    (src_ > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src_[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0)) => math.max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src_ - nLoss) 
    (src_ < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src_[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0)) => math.min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src_ + nLoss)
    (src_ > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0)) => src_ - nLoss
    => src_ + nLoss
```